# How to know what caused the render in React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

I have a React application. I am on a particular page which has a form. I enter details. If I resize the window to mobile view, the page is getting re-rendered because of which the form is becoming empty. Why?

My guess is that some state variable is getting changed while resizing because of which the page is getting rendered again. So, I removed all the state variables of the page and kept a simple

```
return (
    <H1>Hello!</H1
)
```

in the render function. And I still see that the page is getting re-rendered. (I checked it on the

```
useEffect(()=>{
    alert('rendered!!!')
},[])
```

Now, I am not sure if that is the reason why the page is getting re-rendered or something else. Any pointers on why this is happening? If it has to be any state change, how to track which part of the state is getting changed?

Comment: Do you have the "React Developer Tools" installed, an extension for Chrome Browser? You can use the Profiler tool and see why a component rerendered. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html

Comment: Are you handling `e.preventDefault()` in the form submit handler?

Comment: That shouldn't happen purely as a result of a window resize.  I would guess that some component higher up in the tree is being re-rendered as the result of some prop change.  Your `useEffect()` debug line with the empty array indicates that this component is actually being fully re-mounted.  Is the parent applying a `key` to this component that is changing?

Comment: @user2340824 - Thanks for the replies. I found that the page was using a layout which has <Hidden> component of material UI which was causing it. But the problem is that this layout is used for other pages also. It is causing this re-render for specific pages only.